# Remove parent from the XElement

Tags: c#, xml, xelement

how to remove the parent tag from the xml " Tickets" the remaining nodes should be there

```
<Tickets>
    <Extract_Date>2011-02-25 00:00:00</Extract_Date>
    <Ticket>
        <Ticket_Number>INC000000578057</Ticket_Number>
        <Status>
            <Value>Cancelled</Value>
            <Reason>Cancelled by user</Reason>
        </Status>
    </Ticket>
</Tickets>
```

Comment: Delete it by notepad?  Since <tickets> tag has no closing, this is no valid xml file...

Comment: What are you trying to do? All XML documents need to have a single root element containing all the other elements to be considered valid XML. In this instance, `<Tickets></Tickets>` is that element.

Comment: sorry,can you tell how to do this ?

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387051.aspx check out this link msdn site

Comment: @L.B I would have said Ticket except for that Pesky Extract_Date element preceding it.

Comment: want to remove the parent <Tickets>,the link looks like it removes child nodes

Comment: What would you want to do with the children? Ultimately they need to be children of one specific root node.

Comment: ... and you have no node above <tickets> children so you would still need one...

Comment: want to serialize the other nodes and save it to DB,while deserializing adding dynamically the parent.

Answer (score 3):

The `.Elements()` method of `XElement` returns all of the element's children.

```
IEnumerable<XElement> GetElementsWithoutParent(XElement element)
{
    return element.Elements();
}
```

Of course, such a method would be silly when you could just call the `.Elements()` method directly, but it illustrates the point.

Keep in mind that you no longer have an `XElement`, but an `XElement` collection.  You can no longer get the XML representation by simply calling `.ToString()`.  To get the XML, you'll need to use a `StringBuilder` and append each individual element.  And it can't represent an XML document without a root node.

Comment: return element.Elements();it just returns null, dont know why it does that

Comment: @Gani - Please include your C# code in your question.

Comment: i have to serialize the xml without parent otherwise it throws error while deserializing

Comment: @Gani - Please include your C# code in your question.  Click "Edit" under your question, then add some C# code and save changes.

Answer (score 2):

> want to serialize the other nodes and save it to DB,while deserializing adding dynamically the parent

```
XElement newRoot = ........
newRoot.Add(orgXDoc.Element("Tickets").Elements());
```

Comment: wanted to remove the root tag not adding